# Identify domain related important keywords from a given text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, chatbot, text-processing

I am relatively new to the field of NLP/text processing. I would like to know how to identify domain-related important keywords from a given text.
For example, if I have to build a Q&A chatbot that will be used in the Banking domain, the Q would be like: What is the maturity date for TRADE:12345 ?

From the Q, I would like to extract the keywords: maturity date & TRADE:12345.
From the extracted information, I would frame a SQL-like query, search the DB, retrieve the SQL output and provide the response back to the user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is where the work comes in.

Normally people start with a stop word list. There are several, choose wisely. But more than likely you'll experiment and/or use a base list and then add more words to that list.

Depending on the list it will take out

> "what, is, the, for, ?"

Since this a pretty easy example, they'll all do that. But you'll notice that what is being done is just the opposite of what you wanted. You asked for domain-specific words but what is happening is the removal of all that other cruft (to the library).

From here it will depend on what you use. NLTK or Spacy are common choices. Regardless of what you pick, get a real understanding of concepts or it can bite you (like pretty much anything in Data Science).

Expect to start thinking in terms of linguistic patterns so, in your example:

> What is the maturity date for TRADE:12345 ?

'What' is an interrogative, 'the' is a definite article, 'for' starts a prepositional phrase.

There may be other clues such as the ':' or that TRADE is in all caps. But, it might not be.

That should get you started but you might look at some of the other StackExchange sites for deeper expertise.

Finally, you want to break a question like this into more than one question (assuming that you've done the research and determined the question hasn't already been asked -- repeatedly). So, NLTK and NLP are decently new, but SQL queries are usually a Google search.